# Лог передачи файлов на SFTP сервере в Docker контейнере

Tags: docker, sftp, openssh

Нужно писать лог переданых по SFTP файлов. Мой `sshd_conf`:

```
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

PermitRootLogin yes

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes

UsePAM yes

AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
UseDNS no

Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -l VERBOSE -e
```

Ключи хоста сгенерированы зарание:

```
$ ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -f ssh_host_rsa_key
$ ssh-keygen -N "" -t ed25519 -f ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

SFTP сервер запускается в Docker контейнере собраном из Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y openssh-server

RUN echo 'root:123456' | chpasswd

COPY ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
COPY ssh_host_ed25519_key /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN chmod 400 /etc/ssh/*

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e"]
```

Сейчас в выводе получаю только сообщения о подключениях:

```
$ docker run --rm --name sftp-server -p "2222:22" test/sftp
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Server listening on :: port 22.
Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from 172.17.0.1 port 58556 ssh2
```

Однако, ожидаю что вывод был бы таким как описан в [OpenSSH wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting#Logging_SFTP_File_Transfers):

```
Oct 22 11:59:50 server internal-sftp[4929]: open "/home/fred/foo" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0664
Oct 22 11:59:50 server internal-sftp[4929]: close "/home/fred/foo" bytes read 0 written 928
```

Пробовал уровни логирования: INFO, VERBOSE, DEBUG1-3. Все равно нет записей о загрузке файлов.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вам же [порекомендовали](https://serverfault.com/a/968331/292034) добавить опцию `-e`. а facility можно убрать: `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -l INFO -e`

Comment: У меня же есть опция `-e` для запуска `sshd` (см. CMD в Dockerfile)

Comment: но нет при запуске программы sftp-server. см. `$ man sftp-server`

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду так `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -e`, то пропадают даже те логи, которые были раньше

Comment: Суть вопроса еще раз кратко - логи есть, но в них не хватает строк показывающих загрузку/выгрузку файлов. Есть идеи почему так происходит?

Comment: что именно пропадает? и куда делся log-level? `-l INFO` (возможно, стоит повысить до `-l VERBOSE`)

Comment: После запуска есть две строки "Server listening..." и строка "Accepted..." - это логи которые воводятся с опцией `-e`. Если `-e` перенести в `sshd_conf`, то логов вообще нет. Уровни логирования перепробовал все (в вопросе написано какие именно). Изменение Facility (опция `-f`) тоже не дает результатов.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, может быть проблема в Docker? Это все-таки неполноценная виртуальная машина. Например, не запущен какой-нибудь компонент, который следит за файловой системой.

Comment: *Если -e перенести* — зачем??? добавьте опции и у той и у другой программы. // facility — это доп. информация для программ логирования. вы их не используете, потому facility вам не нужен

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за помощь! Исправил `ssh_conf` в описании на акутальные как у себя по вашим рекомендациям. Лог есть, но информация о файлах по-прежнему отсутствует.

Comment: видимо, sshd запускает sftp-server, не подключая его stderr к своему, потому сообщения от sftp-server и теряются. если так, то без какой-нибудь реализации syslogd не обойтись.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а вот тут вы абсолютно правы! Сейчас запустил sshd и rsyslogd через supervisord. В выводе консоли по-прежнему вижу логи только от sshd, но появился файл `/var/log/messages` в котором есть все что нужно, но уже от `sftp-server`. Спасибо!